The animation for the custom view does not play
There is a task to create a custom ViewGroup widget to which you can add only two child elements. Both are centered horizontally, the first one should be placed on the upper border of the parent custom ViewGroup, the second one on the lower border. When adding, an animation should be played: the child element slowly appears in the middle of the ViewGroup and moves to the upper border (for the first element) or to the lower (for the second element) in a fixed time. Here is my code:
class CustomViewGroup @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    @StyleRes defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : ViewGroup(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    private val timeDuration = 2000L
    private val maxChild = 2

    override fun onLayout(p0: Boolean, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int, p4: Int) {
        if (childCount > 0) {
            val firstChild = getChildAt(0)

            if (firstChild != null) {
                firstChild.layout(
                    measuredWidth / 2 - firstChild.measuredWidth / 2,
                    0,
                    measuredWidth / 2 + firstChild.measuredWidth / 2,
                    firstChild.measuredHeight
                )
            }
        }

        if (childCount > 1) {
            val secondChild = getChildAt(1)

            if (secondChild != null) {
                secondChild.layout(
                    measuredWidth / 2 - secondChild.measuredWidth / 2,
                    measuredHeight - secondChild.measuredHeight,
                    measuredWidth / 2 + secondChild.measuredWidth / 2,
                    measuredHeight
                )
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        var maxWidth = 0
        var totalHeight = 0

        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val child = getChildAt(i)
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, child.measuredWidth)
            totalHeight += child.measuredHeight
        }

        val width = resolveSize(maxWidth, widthMeasureSpec)
        val height = resolveSize(totalHeight, heightMeasureSpec)

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?) {

        if (childCount > 2) {
            throw IllegalStateException("Custom view can only have $maxChild children")
        } else {
            super.addView(child)

            if (child != null) {
                startAnimation(child, childCount - 1)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startAnimation(child: View, childIndex: Int) {
        child.alpha = 0f
        val startY = measuredHeight.toFloat() / 2
        val endY = if (childIndex == 0) 0f else measuredHeight.toFloat() - child.measuredHeight

        val translateYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(child, "y", startY, endY)
        val fadeAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(child, "alpha", 0f, 1f)

        val animatorSet = AnimatorSet()
        animatorSet.playTogether(translateYAnimator, fadeAnimator)
        animatorSet.duration = timeDuration
        animatorSet.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        
        animatorSet.start()
    }
}

The problem is that when adding a child View element, the animation of movement is not played, while the animation of slow appearance is visible. Please tell me what could be wrong.
